# In Blazor, how to cascade a parameter from @Body back to the layout?

Tags: blazor, razor-components

I need to change the class of a spinner in the header - show it while data is being fetched and turn it to invisible when done.

Using Cascading Values, I can have in the layout:

```
<CascadingValue Value="classString">
    @Body
</CascadingValue>
```

and in the page I can use `[CascadingParameter] string classStr` to access the value set in the layout.

If I want `classString` in the layout affected by a change to classStr in the page, I can cascade an event, as seen [here](https://www.syncfusion.com/faq/blazor/components/how-do-you-update-the-cascading-values-in-blazor).

But this example cascades the event to a child component with `<ChildComponent OnStrChange="@ChangeStr">` where `OnStrChange` is defined on the child component using [Parameter].

I've tried cascading the event with `<CascadingValue Value="eventName" Name="event">` but that does not seem to work.

Can I cascade an event to a page called with @Body?

Comment: I can see several answers below.  You state "I need to change the class of a spinner in the header - show it while data is being fetched and turn it to invisible when done."  Can you show some code for this.  You're solution seems to revolve around cascading events.  This is probably not the best solution, but without something to work with it's difficult to suggest a better answer.  If the answers below work for you, forget this comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**--edit--**

**@enet beat me to the punch on this one, but I'll leave my answer as a slightly more condensed version.**

**Layout.razor**

```
<CascadingValue Value = "this">
    @AnythingThatNeedsAccesToTheSpinner
</CascadingValue>

@code {
    bool IsSpinning {get; set;}

    public async Task SetSpinner (bool SpinValue){
        IsSpinning=SpinValue;
    }
}
```

**AnythingThatNeedsAccessToTheSpinner.razor**

```
@code{
    [CascadingParameter]
    Layout Layout {get; set;}

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
         await Layout.SetSpinner(true);
         await Task.Delay(5000);
         await Layout.SetSpinner(false);
    }
    
}
```

Comment: although @enet beat you to it, I must mark this as the answer as it is perfectly concise and just works!  The neat thing is it that I can easily extend it with additional members on the Layout component to act as a state object.

Comment: Yes, so long as you stick to the single page and don't use navigation, I think that's right.

Comment: @GilShalit, I'd strongly recommend you not to expose the MainLayout object to children components for such operations as displaying a spinner. There are some issues with this that can lead to subtle abnormalities only Steve Anderson can discover. More importantly, the MainLayout component is re-rendered twice,  each time you use the spinner. Very bad. Very inefficient...  Since your question was about cascading values to the child component, in one of my answer I demonstrated how to cascade the MainLayout object to the child component in order to manipulate the spinner, but then again,

Comment: this is a bad solution. You should use the solution proposed in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69589899/6152891 (under the update section). The first version works perfectly well, but the second one (under the update section) implements a method instead of a property to set the current state. Implementing a method instead of a property is more appropriate, and it is due to a suggestion made by Brian Parker. I could ignore his suggestion, especially because it works, and it is only a matter of style, and yet I choose to adopt his suggestion...

Comment: a method is more appropriate here. But cascading the MainLayout object is not a matter of style... It is problematic. Don't do that like that.

Comment: "The neat thing is it that I can easily extend it with additional members on the Layout component to act as a state object" And then you'll come to stackoverflow to ask what is wrong with your app ;}

Comment: Why would the Layout component be re-rendered if you aren't navigating or reloading the page?  Can you plz demonstrate this?  And if it's bad, terrible, don't ever do it-- why does your answer start with the line `<CascadingValue Value="this">` of `MainLayout`?  I'm confused.

Comment: "Why would the Layout component be re-rendered if you aren't navigating or reloading the page?" You can't render the spinner without re-rendering the MainLayout, unless you use magic. "And if it's bad....I'm confused." No need to be confused. Just read this from my comment above: "Since your question was about cascading values to the child component, in one of my answer I demonstrated how to cascade the MainLayout object to the child component in order to manipulate the spinner, but then again, this is a bad solution."

Comment: What happens if multiple things need the spinner?

Comment: Thanks @enet and Brian Parker for the discussion.  I am going to stay with this method - have added additional pages and seen no ill effect.  It still might happen, and I will keep my eyes open and report back!

Comment: You've got it all wrong. Again, that method is bad and inefficient... Why render the MainLayout twice each time you want to display the Spinner component. The MainLayout  should not handle the state of the Spinner, and the Spinner should re-render itself without the MainLayout being involved. Additionally, rendering the MainLayout component just for the sake of updating the UI may have side effects in the form of unintentionally resetting parameters' values passed to other components.

Comment: @enet  Can you please provide a minimal example that any change to Parameters in a layout page, leads to conditional rendering of a component (like a spinner), causes the resetting of the Layout's Parameter values or a double reload, or provide a link to documentation that says so?

Comment: The above is your answer, right ? You can copy the code, complete what is necessary, and make it work. And see for yourself whether I'm right or wrong. I guess if you've answered the question, you can see and implement the whole thing, though I'm puzzled why you don't understand it.

Comment: @Bennyboy1973, I believe that by now you've verified that displaying the spinner results in the MainLayout component being re-rendered twice, right ?

Answer (score 2):

You can take a really circuitous route where your layout implements an interface like [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/cascading-values-and-parameters?view=aspnetcore-5.0#pass-data-across-a-component-hierarchy-1) and sends itself as a cascading parameter. However, it has other side effects.
The other option is creating a service for seamless communication between components. Basically, you can use:

```
public class SpinnerState
{
    public string SpinnerClass {get;set;}
    public Func<Task> OnSpinnerClassChanged {get;set;}
    public async Task SetSpinnerClass(string newClass)
    {
        SpinnerClass = newClass;
        await OnSpinnerClassChanged.Invoke();
    }
}
```

Inject this as a session service:

```
    services.AddScoped<SpinnerState>();
```

And then use it in the layout

```
@inject SpinnerState state
@implements IDisposable
// hook and unhook event listeners in OnInitialized and Dispose methods respectively

    <div class="@state.SpinnerClass"></div>
    
    @Body //etc


@code
{
    protected override void OnInitialized() 
    { 
       state.OnSpinnerClassChanged += ChangeSpinner;
    }
    async Task ChangeSpinner()
    {
       StateHasChanged();
    }
}
```

When the child component updates the SpinnerClass, the layout will update the state.

Caveats:

1. Ideally, don't do this. i.e. Don't update UIs in the MainLayout. The problem is that every layout level refresh causes refresh of the body. Which, in turn, *might* cause the components to lose their state. Instead, (in the above example) let the spinner component listen to the event. That way, any update to the state is limited to the spinner component only.
2. Updating UI in response to some long running request is what you are actually interested in doing *I guess*. So instead of passing UI attribute updates, raise some functional event (like "UploadingFile" ) and let the individual components respond to it.